# why libxml2 quotes starting double slash in CDATA with javascript

Tags: php, xml, dom, libxml2

This is my code:

```
<?php
$data = <<<EOL
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
    "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var a = 123; // JS code
    //]]>
    </script>
</html>
EOL;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = false;
$dom->loadXml($data);
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($dom->saveXML()) . '</pre>';
```

This is result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
//]]><![CDATA[
var a = 123; // JS code
//]]><![CDATA[
]]></script></html>
```

If and when I remove the `DOCTYPE` notation from XML document, CDATA works properly and leading/trailing double slash is not turned into CDATA.

What is the problem here? Bug in libxml2? PHP version is 5.2.13 on Linux. Thanks.

Comment: libxml2 2.6.32, PHP 5.3.0, Ubuntu 9.04, I see the correct output. I checked the bug database for libxml2 and could not find any bugs that matched this description. You may wish to check it yourself and, if needed, submit a bug report. First you must verify that it is actually libxml2's fault. Don't rule out that it's something with PHP.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on PHP 5.3 / libxml 2.7.7

Comment: Is it possible the line break between the <script> and //<!cdata is throwing things off? Your particular libxml might be highly pedantic and insist on the cdata being absolutely first, with no whitespace (the line break) intervening.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running libxml 2.7.3 with PHP 5.2.11 on OS X.

Not an apples to apples comparison but maybe it will help you.

When I run your code (and add the closing PHP tag here is my output.)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var a = 123; // JS code
    //]]>
    </script></html>
```

It appears to render correctly as you want it to. Maybe the version numbers will help you sort it out... I'm running a older version of PHP5 (Mamp incidentally so I didn't compile it myself.)

Hope this helps point you in a direction to find your answer.

Take care!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My version of libxml is 2.6.16. Maybe this is the problem...

Comment: It is unnecessary and inadvisable to include the closing PHP tag in files that are purely PHP. By including this tag, you are susceptible to already-sent-header errors due to unintended whitespace after any closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the HTML version of the API.
Use `loadHTML` and `saveHTML` instead.